# Is there a programming term for selecting or inserting similar to "upsert"?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

Is there a programming term for a widget/service that has the ability to either select an existing item or create/insert a new item? Maybe like how "upsert" is a combination of **up**dating existing or in**sert**ing new?

**Edit**

Sorry, maybe my use of "upsert" as an example term is causing confusion. I'm looking for a term that describes (*selecting* or *creating*), not (*creating* or *updating*). For example, a widget that can query existing contacts to assign to a company, but also allows ad-hoc creation of contacts as well. I'm hoping to use the term in the name of such widgets to succinctly describe their function.

Comment: I swear, 99% of programming is just thinking up names for stuff :\

Comment: Maybe I need to patent "looksert" as a new term. :)

Comment: going with `cread` as in create or read

Answer (score 1):

In web services based on representational state transfer (REST), the `PUT` method has semantics which can mean `create or modify`. Based on this, I would propose *put* as a possibility.

This also happens to match Java usage of the word: consider the `put` method on Hashtable. It maps a key to a value and returns the old value corresponding to the key, if it existed. This implies it can either exist or not already, and the action will succeed. Mozilla uses the same semantics for `put` on `IDBObjectStore` accessed in JavaScript.

It seems like where *put* is used for updating a collection, it typically has the meaning of *create or update*.

Based on the clarification - something like *provide*, *specify*, *define* or *identify* might be acceptable options for communicating the contents of a collection created by giving existing instances and/or creating new ones on the spot. That is, I can *provide, specify, define* or *identify* a real number by making reference to some well-known ones (pi, sqrt(2), etc.) or by creating a new one (e.g., by listing some digits or describing how it is computed).

Comment: Sorry, maybe my use of "upsert" as an example term is causing confusion. I'm looking for a term that describes (_selecting_ or _creating_), not (_creating_ or _updating_). Please see my updated question.

Comment: @adam0101 I think I understand - so you mean like a widget that does two things, either selecting or creating, and you want a name for the widget's function? For instance, a stack pushes and pops, a queue enqueues and dequeues, a phone places or receives calls. You want a noun for the widget, not a verb for the action. Selecting and creating ae not the same action as they might be for putting in a hash table; they are two distinct functions of a common object.

Comment: A noun would be great but a verb would probably also work by adding "er" to the end of it like `contactAdder`, for example.